# Systems of equation program

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a systems of equations program in C#. I know how to solve the problem on paper, but I'm having a hard time putting it into code. I'm pretty new at this (Started programming less than a month ago, and C# a few days ago), so I know this isn't correct but it is the best I could come up with. I tried searching on here and other sites for something to send me in the right direction, but couldn't find anything. I don't want you to write the entire program for me, just maybe a few lines to give me the right idea. Here is what I have so far, I realize the errors in it and why it doesn't work, I just can't find out how to fix them.

```
            Console.WriteLine("Enter first equation A: ");
            string str1A = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter first equation B: ");
            string str1B = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter first equation C: ");
            string str1C = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the second equation A: ");
            string str2A = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the second equation B: ");
            string str2B = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the second equation C: ");
            string str2C = Console.ReadLine();

            double dbl1A = Convert.ToDouble(str1A);
            double dbl1B = Convert.ToDouble(str1B);
            double dbl1C = Convert.ToDouble(str1C);
            double dbl2A = Convert.ToDouble(str2A);
            double dbl2B = Convert.ToDouble(str2B);
            double dbl2C = Convert.ToDouble(str2C);

            double dbl2AN = dbl2A * -1;
            double dbl2BN = dbl2B * -1;
            double dbl2CN = dbl2C * -1;

            double dbl3A = dbl1A + dbl2AN;
            double dbl3B = dbl1B + dbl2BN;
            double dbl3C = dbl1C + dbl2CN;

            Console.WriteLine(dbl3A + "+" + dbl3B + "+" + dbl3C);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Just walk through what you do on paper, step by step, and write the same instructions into C#. This skill is *vital* to being a programmer. Also, consider using arrays instead of variables "1A, 2A" and you typically don't use hungarian notation in C#.

Comment: And you can also simply write `double dbl3A = dbl1A - dbl2A;` without this obsolete `dbl2AN`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're taking the coefficients for two equations in the form `Ax + By = C` if that's the case the process will be the same as it is on paper.  Multiply each of the second equations' coefficients by `A1/A2` and then subtract them from the corresponding coefficients in the first equation (the result for `A` should be 0).  That gives you an equation of `B*y = C*` (where `B*` and `C*` are values), which you can easily solve for y.  Then plug that `y` back into either original equation and solve for `x`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you step back and consider what you are expecting to be variables that you have expressions to compute and what are numbers to be passed into the program.

Is "First equation A" supposed to be "3x" or "3x=2" or something else for an expression here? Equations will have equal signs and thus would have to be parsed into left and right hand sides I'd suspect. While matrix inversion would be one route to coding a solution, you first have to get the user to input the values for the matrix. For example, consider if you had 2 equations like: x+y=4 and x-y=2. Note that to solve these you could add them and get x=3 while subtraction would give y=1 for a solution using basic row operations.

If you had a matrix where the first row was: (1,1) and the second row was: (1,-1) then you could use a formula to invert it and generate the solutions for my idea on how to handle a 2 x 2 case that likely would generalize to 3 x 3 which could be a bit uglier for calculations.

Comment: Probably the equation is something like `y = A * x^2 + B * x + C` and is always the same. So only the constants A, B and C are changing.